# ffmpeg extraction path cut

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

When I am extracting the subtitles from video files within a folder with ffmpeg, sometimes the path is cut and sometimes not and I don't know why.

I'll be grateful if I can get some answers.

Here is an example :

https://ibb.co/1mT331J

Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash 

DIR="/volume1/homes/Bruno/test"

# Get all the MKV files in this dir and its subdirs

find "$DIR" -type f -name '*.mkv' | while read filename ; do

# Delete the ".mkv"
newfile="$(echo ${filename} |sed -e 's/.mkv//')" ;

ffmpeg -i "$newfile.mkv" "$newfile.ass"


done
```

Comment: You need to amend your script to account for filenames with spaces in them. Look for `find` options to terminate found entries with a NULL-character and find ways to use that output correctly in the following script portions.

Comment: [Understanding `IFS= read -r line`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618).

Comment: And [quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). Double quotes inside and outside of `$()` are independent, so it should be `echo "${filename}"`. Or better `newfile="${filename%.mkv}"`.

Comment: I found the solution thank you, I added </dev/null at the end of the ffmpeg line !

Comment: Or just use `-nostdin` option in `ffmpeg`.  Also, use [bash parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) instead of `sed`. Take a look at shellcheck.net for suggestions for your script.